# How to detect a alert in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

How can I detect if after a navigation the page shows an alert with some message.

Can puppeteer detect or identify if the page has shown an alert box.

I tried

```
page.on('popup', ()=> {
   console.log('popup detected');
});
```

also,

```
page.on('dialog', ()=> {
   console.log('popup detected');
});
```

Comment: The event handlers have to be registered before doing the  `page.goto`call. Is that maybe your problem?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean can you please show me how it is done with a snippet?

Comment: I meant, the code you posted needs to be called before `page.goto`. Maybe can you post your full code?

Comment: ```let status = await this.page.on('dialog', (data)=> {
            return {code: 444, status: 'Incorrect credentials'}
});
console.log(status.code);
await this.page.goto(stepOneUrl, {waitUntil: 'load'});```
Can you tell me if how I can return the required object as what I am doing is not working.

And thanks now able to detect the popup.

Comment: Glad it worked, added it as an answer. If I understand your code correct, you can set a variable in the outer scope. But I'm not sure if I fully understand what the code is trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments: If you register the event handlers (your code) after calling `page.goto` the event is already triggered before you are listening for the event.

Therefore, make sure to call `page.goto` after your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my two cents :

```
 private async gotoPage(path):Promise<Response|Result> {
        return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
            await Promise.all([
                this.page.on('dialog', async (dialog) => {
                    await dialog.dismiss().catch(() => {
                        console.log(dialog.message());
                        return new Result(TestStatus.FAIL, dialog.message());
                    });
                }),
                this.page.goto(`${this.baseURL}${path}`),
                this.page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' })]).then(
                async () => {
                    resolve(new Result(TestStatus.PASS, `Loading to path success : ${path}`));
                },
                async () => {
                    reject(new Result(TestStatus.FAIL, `Could not GotoPage : ${path}`));
                });
        });
    }
```